# Override Onepage Checkout Page Layout - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, onepage-checkout

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

This is the layout defined for checkout `(layout="checkout")`, I want to override this to `1column`, however playing a `checkout_index_index.xml` file in my theme's Magento_Checkout override directory replaces the entire layout and leaves me with a blank page, whereas a `checkout_index_index.xml` file in a custom module has no effect.

Is this a load order problem or am I making a beginner mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what is meant by Override, override will completely ignore the base file so only your file will be read. This is why the code from the original file is not being rendered.

To make your change on top of the existing code you want to **extend** the file.

Instructions for extending can be found [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-extend.html).

```
<module_dir>
 |__/view
   |__/frontend
     |__/layout
       |--<layout1>.xml
       |--<layout2>.xml
```

Comment: That is what I tried, and it completely replaces the file, which is what I expected... however I only tried that as adding the layout file in a custom module had no effect (even when set to load after Magento_Checkout), please could you re-read the question?

Comment: Extending/overriding XML via a module is the same as in a theme with the addition of the `view` directory. If you add it to `Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/layout_handle.xml` it will extend the XML, to override it you'll need to add it to `Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/override/themeName/layout_handle.xml`. If your file follows the same structure it should be working.

Comment: Ah, as far as I know I was only trying to override the module's layout file - not a parent. I simply want to change the page layout from "checkout" to 2columns or 1column.

Edit: I have never seen the term "override" in any path in any documentation, ever. Is this something that has been carried over from Magento 1?

Comment: Nope it's a new feature for M2, if you include the file the 'normal' way it will extend it. If you use the override directory it will completely remove it, that's why I was confused earlier :P. 

You seem to be doing the correct thing though, extending it and changing the layout should do it, with a cache flush of course. Even the dev docs say this so if it isn't working I'd suspect a typo, cache issue or something like that - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_columns

Comment: If you still don't have any luck can you update your question with the full file paths and content please, I'll see if I can find out why it isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

you are making a beginner mistake, keep extended file blank and only add the lines which needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change this layout to "1column".

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"/>
```

Make sure you have applied your theme under **Content** > **Configuration** in admin